# Find particular format in Pandas Dataframe Cell

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I need to check if the content in each cell of a column follows a particular format.

```
Index    Column A
0        abcd
1        abc_1
2        abc_xy
3        abc_12
4        zabc_12
```

How can I go about finding cells that match the format: '**abc_ + number**' such that the values in index 1 and 3 would be found. 
So far I know how I can look for the 'abc_' or numeric part of the cell using regex:

```
re.match('abc_', df['Column A'])
```

But I am not sure how to look for the complete pattern. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['Column A'].str.contains(r'^abc_\d')
```

Or, if that pattern should match the whole string

```
df['Column A'].str.contains(r'^abc_\d+$')
```

Note that by default, the `pat` argument is treated as a regex, so you do not have to use `regex=True`. You may use a `na` argument to define a fill value for missing values.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string (you need it here as `str.contains` uses `re.search`, not `re.match` and thus does not anchor the match at the start of the string)
- `abc_` - a literal substring
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @MAK7 I have just added the pattern explanation, it is important here.

Comment: Super helpful, much appreciated. I was just about to ask that wouldn't ```\d``` just look for a single digit. The ```+$``` caters to that!

Comment: @MAK7 It also depends on the actual requirement. If there should be end of string after the digits, `^abc_\d+$` is the right pattern. If you need to make sure the string starts with `abc_<digit>` then `^abc_\d` is fine. Both patterns do what you asked for, they return Row 1 and 3.